# Arquivo Java não recebe parâmetros pelo InputStream

Tags: java, redmine

Tenho um problema com uma classe em meu servidor de aplicação do projeto. Preciso que esta classe após compilada e executando, receba uma mensagem:

- ou "MSG_PV" ou "MSG_RV" do meu REDMINE, para publicar projetos
- ou gerar os mesmos, dentro do meu Repositório.

O problema é que implementei a função de *Publicar Projeto* agora, sendo que a de *Gerar* já estava em funcionamento em meu servidor. Li algo na net e na documentação do `JAVADOC` que o método `InputStream` quando usado com o `readLine()`, passa a ser o `InputStreamReader` no Java 7.

Como proceder diante desta situação?

Meu código:

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.*;

public class server_versao extends Thread
{
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;
   private boolean server_is_busy  = false;

   public server_versao(int port) throws IOException
   {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
   }

   private boolean execute_MSG_RV(String branch){
      try{
        if (Integer.parseInt(branch.substring(1,5)) >= 1308) //Versoes B1308 pra cima.
            return release_branch("release1308 " + branch);
        else
            return release_branch("release " + branch);
      }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
      }
   }

   private boolean release_branch(String comando){
     boolean result = false;
     InputStream is;
     Process p;
     BufferedReader br;
     BufferedWriter bw;
     Date today;
     SimpleDateFormat ft;
     File f;
     FileWriter fw; 
     String aux, arch = "";

     try{
        today = new Date();
        ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy-hh.mm");
        f = new File ("logs/release/log-"+ft.format(today)+".txt");
        fw = new FileWriter(f);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        System.out.println("Executando comando: "+ comando);
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("cmd /c gera_release.bat"+comando.toUpperCase());
        is = p.getInputStream(); 
        br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is)); 
        aux = br.readLine(); 

        while (aux!=null){ 
            arch += aux + "\r\n";
            if (aux.contains("BUILD SUCCESSFUL") == true)
                result = true;
            aux = br.readLine();
        }

        bw.write(arch);
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
        result = false;
     }
     return result;
   }

  private boolean execute_MSG_PV(String branch){
      try{
        if (Integer.parseInt(branch.substring(1,5)) >= 1308) //Versoes B1308 pra cima.
            return publish_version("publicar versoes_novas " + branch);
        else
            return publish_version("publicar versoes_antigas " + branch);
      }catch(Exception ex){
        return false;
      }
   }

   private boolean publish_version(String comando){
     boolean result = false;
     InputStream is;
     Process p;
     BufferedReader br;
     BufferedWriter bw;
     Date today;
     SimpleDateFormat ft;
     File f;
     FileWriter fw; 
     String aux, arch = "";

     try{
        today = new Date();
        ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy-hh.mm");
        f = new File ("logs/publish/log-"+ft.format(today)+".txt");
        fw = new FileWriter(f);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        System.out.println("Executando comando: "+ comando);
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("cmd /c publicar_versao.bat"+comando.toUpperCase());
        is = p.getInputStream(); 
        br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is)); 
        aux = br.readLine(); 

        while (aux!=null){ 
            arch += aux + "\r\n";
            if (aux.contains("BUILD SUCCESSFUL") == true)
                result = true;
            aux = br.readLine();
        }

        bw.write(arch);
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
        result = false;
     }
     return result;
   }

   public void run()
   {
      boolean success = false;
      String msg;
      while(true)
      {
         try
         {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStreamReader());
            msg = in.readLine();
            if (msg.equals("MSG_RV"))
                success = execute_MSG_RV(in.readLine());
            else if(msg.equals("MSG_PV"))
                success = execute_MSG_PV(in.readLine());

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            if (success)
                out.writeUTF("MSG_SUC");
            else
                out.writeUTF("MSG_ERR");
            server.close();
         }catch(IOException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      try
      {
         Thread t = new server_versao(port);
         t.start();
      }catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Quando o arquivo recebe os parâmetros dentro deste bloco:

```java
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStreamReader()); 
msg = in.readLine(); 
if (msg.equals("MSG_RV")) 
    success = execute_MSG_RV(in.readLine()); 
else if(msg.equals("MSG_PV")) 
    success = execute_MSG_PV(in.readLine());
```

Deveria passar para a função chamada o que se encontra dentro de `in.readLine()` e completar o restante das chamadas. Porém fiz um debug e ele lê os dados mas não processa. Parece estar havendo um erro com meu `in.readline()`

Comment: "Porém fiz um debug e ele lê os dados mas não processa." Pode ser mais específico? Como você confirmou que os dados estão sendo lidos? E "não processa" significa o quê, que dá algum erro, que lança uma exceção... A propósito, [`DataInputStream.readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29) está obsoleto, pode causar problemas de encoding, use `BufferedReader` em vez disso.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a documentação a função readLine de DataInputStrem esta descontinuada como se pode ver [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29)

Tente trocar para:

```
    BufferedReader d
      = new BufferedReader(server.getInputStreamReader());
```